# Should I delete my poorly worded questions

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, banning

I recently received a question ban from Stack Overflow. In the section about [lifting your ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) it is stated that I should update all of my questions, specifically those that scored zero points or less. The problem I have now is that for some questions, I no longer know what I wanted to express at that time. Should I just delete the question, and if I do, can I still get out of the ban?

Comment: Do you no longer know what you wanted to express at that time because you cannot remember some technical details? Or because you cannot comprehend your own question?

Comment: It's a mix of both, actually

Comment: As for the latter part of your question, note that deleted questions will continue to count against you and deletion itself will actually hurt you if the question is less than 30 days old: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: So do you have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: It looks like you only have one negatively scored question. Have you already deleted some?

Comment: Start with putting enough code in your questions to duplicate the issue. In your most recent questions you had a habit of only including some code and sometimes including the rest of it in a pen or fiddle. Also double check spelling and grammar while you're making edits.

Comment: Umm... you have two deleted, closed and negatively scored questions... Sadly, I can't see anyway they can possibly be salvaged...

Comment: Your UUID question would be improved by an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I found a solution for the UUID problem (like a year ago), I just will have to use some time to find it again. Also @Don't Panic, there was a question I deleted some time ago, but I don't know which one it was. For the other one, I don't know, maybe you can tell me how to find them?

Comment: You should see a link for "deleted recent questions" at the bottom of the questions tab in your profile. I don't know what the cut-off for "recent" is, though.

Comment: I must have deleted it some time ago, since it is no longer shown there.

Answer (score 2):

If the questions are problematic, then deleting them won't help you to get out of a question ban. That should be pretty clear from [the Help Center page you read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

You absolutely need to figure out a way to fix the problems with your old questions. If you don't know what you were trying to ask at the time, then that's okay, albeit kind of inconvenient. Here's what you should do:

1. If the question already has answers, then use *those* to figure out what you must have been asking at the time. Rewrite the question to match what the one that the answers are answering.
2. If the question *doesn't* have any answers, then it doesn't matter what you were meaning to ask at the time. All that matters is whether you can turn the question into something sensible and useful *now*. If that means completely rewriting it, even rewriting it into something entirely new, then that's okay, since you aren't invalidating the effort others have put into it.

[This would be a good question to start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946181/how-do-i-make-a-custom-range-input-slider-using-javascript), since it has a score of −2. As it is currently worded, it is begging to be closed as "off-topic → requesting an off-site resource", but I'm going to hold off on that and give you a chance to fix it up. I think it *is* salvageable, and it *has* received an answer, so this is worth doing. Rewrite it so that the *body* of the question is actually asking what the *title* of the question does. In other words, don't ask us to link you to a library; ask how to accomplish the thing you want to accomplish. It would very much help if you could edit in some more context and perhaps even a sample of partially-working code that you want to fix. (Again, if you have to write this after-the-fact, that's okay. Questions don't need to be a perfect record of what was in your head at the time. They need to be *clear* and *useful*.)

Also, while you're going through and cleaning up your old questions, please edit out signatures, salutations, and benedictions. Your posts are already signed with your user card, so you don't need your name. Don't thank people in advance; wait and thank them after they post a useful answer by upvoting that answer.

I can't really give you specific help on how to improve your other questions because I'm not knowledgeable about the relevant technologies. But the good is that they're only zero-scored, so they probably are not *that* far off, and you don't have *that* deep of a hole to dig yourself out of. A couple of positively-scored contributions, and you will probably be back in good standing (or, at least, given a second chance).

The most glaring problem with your account are two deleted questions, as already mentioned by Jon Clements. These are scored at −5 and −6, respectively, so they're certainly weighing you down. (You didn't delete either of these; the community did, after they were closed.) Unfortunately, there isn't a whole lot you can do about those. [One of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281381/best-programming-language-for-string-operations) asks about the "best programming language for string operations", which is absolutely not salvageable to our standards. [The other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313084/dont-update-data-with-every-page-load) is asking about not updating data with each page-load using PHP. As I said, I don't know anything about PHP, so I can't say whether or not this is potentially salvageable. [Jon seems to think it isn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354233/should-i-delete-my-poorly-worded-questions#comment499456_354233). Either way, it's probably best to focus on the questions that *aren't* deleted and avoid digging up old problems for now.